# How can I undo Evince highlighting for PDF files?

Tags: linux, evince

After highlighting some texts in Evince ("Annotate the Document"->"Add highlight annotation"), how can I undo the highlighting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click on the highlighted text, then click *Remove annotation*.

Comment: Where you have to click may be a little off if you're looking at a math document. I got frustrated because when I was right clicking on the highlighted text, no option to remove annotation showed up.

But then I moved the cursor to slightly above the highlighted text and the cursor changed and then I was able to remove it.

Comment: And what if the annotation has no size at all?

Comment: Same issue: sometimes remove annotation not available (bugged), at which time maybe `Master PDF Editor 5` to the rescue.

Answer (score 1):

You could reload the PDF to remove the annotations and highlights provided you didn't save it yet.